# What is BitInstant's "spot" price when sending to BitCoin Address?

Tags: bitinstant

Bitinstant hasn't replied to my "contact us" and customer service emails - does anyone know why they do not post a current exchange rate on their page? Has anyone used BitInstant, funding from Dwolla and paying out to a bitcoin address?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the claim that they convert at the last trade at Mt. Gox as-of the time that ZipZap notifies them of the transaction.

Due to the Moneygram --> ZipZap interface, and then the ZipZap --> BitInstant, followed by the BitInstant --> Coinapult (which does the exchange) there isn't any strictly followed timeline as far as how long after you've handed over the cash before your coins are sent to you.